# ng-repeat inserting empty anchor tags

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-controller

I'm trying to create a menu using angular. A menu item can have children requiring another ng-repeat to print the sub nav items. I'm noticing some strange behavior when attempting to insert an anchor tag within the 2nd ng-repeat.

Link to fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/npU7t/

```
<li ng-repeat="sub_menu_item in menu_item.sub_menu">
    <a href="">
        {{ sub_menu_item.title }}
    </a>
</li>
```

With

```
{
    title: 'menu item with children',
    sub_menu: [
        {
            title: '<-- empty anchor tag???'
        }
    ]
}
```

Results in

```
<li ng-repeat="sub_menu_item in menu_item.sub_menu" class="ng-scope">
    <a href=""></a>
    <a href="" class="ng-binding"><-- empty anchor tag???</a>
</li>
```

Where the did duplicate / empty anchor tag come from? How can I prevent it from being created?

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't a bug with Angular, but rather how you have your markup.

### UPDATE:

The issue is actually the nested `<a>` tag, not the `<ul>` tag.

```
<a href="">
     <span class="title">{{ menu_item.title }}</span>
     <ul class="sub-menu" ng-if="menu_item.sub_menu">
         <li ng-repeat="sub_menu_item in menu_item.sub_menu">
             <a href="">
                 {{ sub_menu_item.title }}
             </a>
         </li>
     </ul>
</a>
```

In fact, if you remove Angular from the equation altogether, you will see that the extraneous `<a>` tag is still added to the DOM: http://jsfiddle.net/jwcarroll/cXkj4/

If you get rid of the nested `<a>` tag, then the extra element will disappear.

```
<a href="">
   <span class="title">{{ menu_item.title }}</span>
</a>
<ul class="sub-menu" ng-if="menu_item.sub_menu">
   <li ng-repeat="sub_menu_item in menu_item.sub_menu">
       <a href="">
           {{ sub_menu_item.title }}
       </a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

In both [HTML 4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtds.html#dtdentry_xhtml1-strict.dtd_a.content), and [HTML 5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element), having a nested `<a>` tag is a no no.

The simplest possible recreation of the problem I could come up with [is this bit of markup](http://jsfiddle.net/jwcarroll/HQsxw/):

```
<a href="">Outer
    <p>Blah
        <a href="">Inner</a>
    </p>
</a>
```

Because you can't nest `<a>` elements within each other, the browser is doing it's best to recreate your intent while keeping the DOM clean. What you end up with is this:

```
<a href="">Outer</a>
<p>
   <a href="">Blah</a>
   <a href="">Inner</a>
</p>
```

This makes sense when you realize what the browser is trying to do. The browser is trying to do three things:

1. Keep `Outer`, `Blah` and `Inner` text elements inside hyperlinks
2. Contain `Blah` and `<a>Inner</a>` inside a single `<p>` tag
3. Ensure no `<a>` tags are nested within each other

The only sensible way to accomplish all three of these is to wrap both `Outer` and `Blah` text elements in separate `<a>` tags in a way that isn't nested. This is the closest approximation to the original intent without breaking the DOCTYPE rules.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Very strange. It doesn't appear with any tag besides `<a>` (like `<p>` or `<div>`). It looks like an outright bug to me - I'd submit a proper [bug report](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues).

Comment: I tried several other tags, seems like the anchor tag is the only one.