# ng-repeat list item is not rendering inside the anchor

Tags: angularjs

So heres what the html looks like in the text editor...

```
<div  ng-repeat="x in Result">
   <a ng-href="https://domain.com/{{x.short_url}}">
     <li class="viewer" id="{{x.user_id}}"  style="background-image: url(https://domain.com/{{x.user_id}})">
   </a>
</div>
```

But when its rendered in the browser it looks like this...

```
<a ng-href="https://domain.com/ucmzda" href="https://domain.com/ucmzda"></a>
 <li class="viewer" id="b5599b09bcb3467ba3ade4e5b30721a4" style="background-image: url(https://domain.com/image/user/b5599b09bcb3467ba3ade4e5b30721a4)">
```

I cant figure out why the list item is not rendering inside the anchor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div  ng-repeat="x in Result">
   <a ng-href="https://domain.com/{{x.short_url}}">
     <li class="viewer" id="{{x.user_id}}"  style="background-image: url(https://domain.com/{{x.user_id}})"><li>
   </a>
</div>
```

Comment: You got it, that list item needed closing inside the anchor, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

refer:
[ng-repeat inserting empty anchor tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24153850/ng-repeat-inserting-empty-anchor-tags)
**In your case li is not closed:**

It is not a good practies to use li inside a tag:
use like this

```
<ul ng-repeat="x in Result">

     <li class="viewer" id="{{x.user_id}}"  style="background-image: url(https://domain.com/{{x.user_id}})"><a ng-href="https://domain.com/{{x.short_url}}">
   </a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Have you by any chance configured your $locationProvider to html5Mode? If yes this would cause your problems. You could force it to always go to the url by adding target="_self" to your tag. Give it a shot.**
use HTML5 so adding the target="_self" it will work

Comment: I really appreciate your help with this, I added the target="_self"  and moved the anchor just like your code above, but the browser renders the anchor after the list item. I just cant get the anchor to wrap around list item. Very frustrating, but again thank you.